# tikz-cd communative diagram does not render correctly in beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-cd

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[serif, professionalfont]{beamer}[20pt]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{concrete}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A\ar{r}{e}\& B\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when it is compiled as part of a beamer presentation it displays as follows

> A    B    --e-->

instead of

> A --e--> B

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't get your result with a standard preamble. Can you add some additional info on your code? If possible make your code compilable, or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Here is my preamble: \documentclass[serif, professionalfont]{beamer}[20pt]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{concrete}

Comment: I still get the corrected output.

Comment: I had some other macro definitions in the document - when I removed them I too got the right output - I must have overridden a tikz-cd macro without knowing it. I'll just have to go through them one by one to find the guilty party - thanks for help!

Comment: @karlkoeller, sorry. It makes use of `matrix`. OK. My fault.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is originated from a personalized user macro changing the settings hence making it not reproducible